# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (VueJS)

Tags: jquery, vue.js, semantic-ui

I've started a VueJS project with:

```
vue init webpack my-project
```

And got jQuery with npm:

```
npm install jquery
```

And i put this line on my main.js file:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

Either way, i can't use this piece of code: (from semantic ui)

```
$('.ui.rating')
  .rating()
;
```

Because i get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` This is error is most of the time related to not having installed Jquery or not having it declared properly.

Comment: You may need to do `require('jquery').default` but don't quote me on that. You should really be using `import` here I think, though.

Comment: Why window.$ instead of only $?  
You may have to use a mixin or similar to use it in a property

Answer (score 21):

If you have jQuery installed via npm, just import it like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

And inside your methods, you can start using `$` as:

```
methods: {
  getFoo() {
    $( "div.foo" ).html();
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives me the same problem

Comment: Note that you need to import it in the file it is used in, not your main.js file (or whatever you call your starting js file). So you need to import it in each file you use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to keep your **jQuery** code separated from **Vue** code. You can achieve that by creating a jQuery file in assets and use **ECMAScript** `export` and `import` feature.

```
 //your jQuery functions file e.g main.js
    import $ from 'jQuery' //import jQuery 

    export function somethingWithjQuery(){
     console.log($)
     }
```

And inside of your **Vue** component you can do something like this:

```
 import {somethingWithjQuery} from './assets/js/main'

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            Hello
        },
        mounted() {
            somethingWithjQuery()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working for me as well but I did this following trick. At first I installed jquery with

```
npm install jquery
```

I did not need to make jquery global or the $ global in my in my main.js. Instead I directly imported it in the components

```
  <template>
  <div>
  <ul class="nav">
  <li class="active">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </template>
  <script>
  import jquery from 'jquery'
  export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },
  data(){
  return {

  }
 },
 mounted(){
 this.$nextTick(()=>{
 jquery('.nav').hide()
       })
  }
 }
 </script>
```

So just use jquery instead of the $ sign.